# How do projects keep multiple build systems in sync?

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio, build

After being forced to work more with Windows at work I'm starting to find that quite a few OpenSource projects do come with support for several build environments.  But how do they keep them all in sync (source files that are added and removed, a consistent set of compiler flags -- all the things that go into vs solutions, gmake files, eclipse projects, etc)?  (Surely they don't keep multiple versions of VS around and manually keep solution- and project files up-to-date!)

I know CMake can generate files for multiple environments (GnuMake, Eclipse, Visual Studio, etc), but the generated files are still tied to CMake--changes to CMakeLists.txt files result in regeneration.  I haven't found any projects using CMake that check the generated files, so I'm wondering what other options there are.

Comment: Oups, clearly my question is terribly written.  I'll rewrite the question to make it less likely to be misunderstood :)

Comment: [duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505639/how-to-setup-visual-studio-for-cross-platform-c-development/)

Comment: Well, that possible duplicate points out using a x-platform build system such as CMake. But as I point out above I've already considered CMake and find it lacking in that the generated makefiles/VS-solution/etc are tied to CMake.  I'd like to be able to ship generated makefiles/VS-solution/etc without forcing the receiver to install the makefile generator.