# Cross-Platform C++ development with VisualStudio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, cross-platform

I want to start a cross-platform C++ project with VisualStudio 2019.
After some research I found two possible ways:

### CMake

[Tutorial: Create C++ cross-platform projects in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/get-started-linux-cmake?view=vs-2019)

[Create and configure a Linux CMake project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/linux/cmake-linux-project?view=vs-2019)

CMake is pretty common for cross-platform projects, but I haven't done much with it and it feels like you need to put in much effort to make it run as you want to. But you have a huge amount of possibilities to configure it. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505639/how-to-setup-visual-studio-for-cross-platform-c-development) SO questions also recommends CMake, but says that there are other ways.

### VS Shared Project

[Shared Project : An Impressive Feature of Visual Studio 2015](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/7ca517/shared-project-an-impressive-features-of-visual-studio-201/)

[Cross-platform code sharing with Visual C++](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cross-platform-code-sharing-with-visual-c/)

If you use cross-platform code sharing in VS you have several projects in your solution (one for each platform) and at least one shared project, which includes your source + header files. The platform specific projects include all the configuration settings and the program entry point. The shared code can be used from each project as if it is in the project.
All the configuration is possible in VS. It looks less complex but with limited possibilities.

### Question

Both ways look like they would fit my needs, but I haven't found a comparison between them. I already coded running examples for both of them, but those small code bases haven't given me the insight I need.

What are the pro's and con's of those two ways? Considering attributes like build-speed, flexibility, time to learn/master/market, VS feature support, unit testing, continuous integration, ...

Comment: I would suggest don't depend on an IDE! What happens if you don't can't or want use Visual Studio anymore? Then all your compile-configurations have to be transformed to some other. When using CMake you can use any IDE you want and have an "easy" tool on the terminal, which you can use in scripts for testing etc. Building Qt applications was much faster for me with CMake (because of qt compiling... ), then with "native" visual studio (800% sometimes) but I never tried the shared projects.

Comment: I have no idea about the difference that you asked, but it seems you can try Visual Studio Code, it is also a good way to start cross-platform development and it seems less complex.

Comment: @RoQuOTriX in our development department everyone has and uses VS so that wouldn't be a problem. Building speed on the other hand is much more relevant.

Comment: @izlin yeah, you are using it for now. But times are changing. I would really seperate my IDE from code management

Comment: "What are the pro's and con's of those two ways?" - Questions of such sort are usually not suitable for Stack Overflow, as it is NOT a discussion forum.Things like "time to learn/master/market" are hardly can be objective. The same for the most of other attributes you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Premake](https://premake.github.io/). You can generate Makefiles and VS project from simple lua configurations. Not a lot of projects use premake but my experience so far has been positive.

Comment: Interesting concept, but this doesn't target my question. You may want to add it as a comment instead.